# Android TextView leaks with setMovementMethod

Tags: android, listview, memory-leaks, textview, linkmovementmethod

I have a `ListView` and in it's `adapter`'s `getView` method, I return a `RelativeLayout` with `MyButton` inside it.

`MyButton` has a `textView` and I have clickable words inside it (`ClickableSpan`).

To make this work, I start with thew following line:
`textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`

Everything works perfectly but MAT shows that `MyButton` leaks because of `textView`. When I comment out the line above, nothing leaks.

Shall I set `movementMethod` to `null`? But even if so, I can't know the destruction moment of the button to set that to `null` as it is inside of many other views.

What am I doing wrong? How to prevent this leak?

[image]

**update**

Solved the leak by setting text to empty string inside `onDetachedFromWindow`, but I am still trying to find a documentation related to this behaviour. Why should I set the `textview` to `""`?

Comment: try View.onDetachedFromWindow()

Comment: @pskink Thank you, setting `movementMethod` to `null` did not work but setting text to `""` did work. (in onDetachedFromWindow). If you also know the reason of this leak, please post as an answer so I can mark it as accepted answer. I am still curious why this leak happens. There are no documentation related to this behaviour.

Comment: I've been using [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) to track down a memory leak, and ultimately found `TextView.setMovementMethod()` was the culprit. Unfortunately for me, setting the movement method to null and the text to "" in `onDetachedFromWindow()` hasn't solved the problem.

LeakCanary shows that it has something to do with `ViewTreeObserver` not having a preDraw listener cleared. Given that `TextView` implements `OnPreDrawListener`, I wonder if that's doing something funky under the hood?

Answer (score 8):

I faced another memory leak with `TextView`, `ClickableSpan`, and `LinkMovementMethod` while making hyperlinks inside a `Fragment`. After the first click on the hyperlink and rotation of the device, it was impossible to click it again due to NPE.

In order to figure out what's going on, I made an investigation and here is the result.

`TextView` saves a copy of the field `mText`, that contains `ClickableSpan`, during the `onSaveInstanceState()` into the instance of static inner class `SavedState`. It happens only under certain conditions. In my case, it was a `Selection` for the clickable part, which is set by `LinkMovementMethod` after the first click on the span.

Next, if there is a saved state, `TextView` performs restoration for the field `mText`, including all spans, from `TextView.SavedState.text` during `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Here is a funny part. When `onRestoreInstanceState()` is called? It’s called after `onStart()`. I set a new object of `ClickableSpan` in `onCreateView()` but after `onStart()` the old object replaces new one which leads to the big problems.

So, the solution is quite simple but is not documented – perform setup of `ClickableSpan` during `onStart()`.

You can read the full investigation on my blog [TextView, ClickableSpan and memory leak](http://kaizendeveloper.com/textview-clickablespan-memory-leak/) and play with the [sample project](https://github.com/JohnKuper/blog-samples/tree/master/SpannableLeak).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i've tried but it seem happens. By creating custom class extends from ClickableSpan(), NoCopySpan the issue is gone

Answer (score 3):

Using `ClickableSpan` may still cause leaks even on versions higher than `KitKat`. If you look into implementation of the `ClickableSpan` you will notice that it doesn't extend `NoCopySpan`, so it leaks in `onSaveInstanceState()` like described in @DmitryKorobeinikov and @ChrisHorner answers. So the solution would be to create a custom class that extends `ClickableSpan` and `NoCopySpan`.

```
class NoCopyClickableSpan(
    private val callback: () -> Unit
) : ClickableSpan(), NoCopySpan {

    override fun onClick(view: View) {
        callback()
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
It turned out that this fix leads to crashes on some devices when Accessibility services are enabled.

Comment: I had to move on with my dirty solution in the day I asked this question. Soon I will try this one again. Thank you for sharing this.

Comment: Added `NoCopySpan`, no more leaks. Thank you for the solution

Comment: After this fix I start getting app crashes when view with such span is shown and accessability service is on. Checked on Samsung devices. Mentioning this for historical purpose as there's no such crash anywhere in the web.

Comment: @Lingviston Thanks for the response! I ended up reverting the fix too due to these crashes. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is most likely caused by `NoCopySpan`. Prior to KitKat, TextView would make a copy of the span and place it in a Bundle in `onSaveInstanceState()` using a SpannableString. SpannableString does not drop NoCopySpans for some reason, so the saved state holds a reference to the original TextView. This was [fixed](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/af7dcdf35a37d7a7dbaad7d9869c1c91bce2272b) for subsequent releases.

Setting the text to "" fixes the issue because the original text containing the NoCopySpan is GC'd properly.

[LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary)'s suggested work around for this is...

> Hack: to fix this, you could override TextView.onSaveInstanceState(), and then use reflection to access TextView.SavedState.mText and clear the NoCopySpan spans.

LeakCanary's exclusion entry for this leak can be [found here](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/blob/master/leakcanary-android/src/main/java/com/squareup/leakcanary/AndroidExcludedRefs.java#L58).

Comment: I can reproduce this on Android 5.1.1 too.

Answer (score 2):

After spending a few hours trying these answers out I came up with my own that finally worked.

I'm not sure how accurate this is and don't understand why this is but it turned out that setting my `TextView`'s movementMethod to null in `onDestroy()` solved the problem.

If anyone knows why please tell me. I'm so boggled because it doesn't seem like `LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()` has a reference to the `TextView` or the activity.

Here's the code

```
override fun onStart() {
    ...
    text_view.text = spanString
    text_view.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod
} 

override fun onDestroy() {
    text_view.text = ""
    text_view.movementMethod = null
}
```

It worked without setting `text_view.text = ""` but I kept it their because of @Chris Horner answer that there might be a problem prior to KitKat.

Answer (score 1):

Try to initialize the ClickableSpan in `onStart()` method.Like

```
onStart(){
super.onStart()
someTextView.setText(buildSpan());
}
```

There is problem with Span on some Android versions. Sometimes it causes memory leaks. More info in this article [TextView, ClickableSpan and memory leak](http://kaizendeveloper.com/textview-clickablespan-memory-leak/)

I hope it will help.